# Не получается настроить рассылку (Celery + Django)

Tags: django, task, celery, рассылка

Имеется модель юзера

```
class BotUser(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.BigIntegerField('Чат ID', null=True, blank=True)

    APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Сотрудник БА'),
        ('2', 'Экипаж'),
        ('3', 'Авиакомпания'),
        ('4', 'Фрилансер'),
        ('5', 'Пассажир')
    )
    category = models.CharField('Категория',max_length=120, null=True, blank=True, default='0',choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES)
```

Так же есть модель для опроса с возможностью оповещения

```
class Question(TranslatableModel):
    APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Сотрудник БА'),
        ('2', 'Экипаж'),
        ('3', 'Авиакомпания'),
        ('4', 'Фрилансер'),
        ('5', 'Пассажир')
    )
    category = models.CharField('Категория',max_length=120, null=True, blank=True, default='0',choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES) 
    translations = TranslatedFields(interview = models.TextField('Опрос', null=True, blank=True),)
    nofify = models.BooleanField('Оповестить пользователей о новом вопросе', default=False, blank=True)
```

Далее я подключаю селери и пытаюсь сделать ф-цию

```
@task
def send(user_category):
    try:
        bot = telebot.TeleBot('*****:AAGcHJX1AfS***JulZjC9h9FVdR7BzyrI')
        if user_category == '0':
            for user in BotUser.objects.all():
                try:
                    mes = 'Появился новый опрос! \nНажмите на кнопку «Опросы» чтоб принять участие'
                    bot.send_message(user.chat_id, mes)
                    return HttpResponse('OK')

                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
        else:       
            for user in BotUser.objects.filter(category=user_category):
                try:    
                    mes = 'Появился новый опрос! \nНажмите на кнопку «Опросник» чтоб принять участие'
                    bot.send_message(user.chat_id, mes)
                    return HttpResponse('OK')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bot.send_message(359144124, str(e))
```

И добавлю в конец 2 модели(Question) вот такой код

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None and self.nofify == True:
            send((self.category,))

        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Т.е вот исходный код всего класса

```
class Question(TranslatableModel):

    APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Сотрудник БА'),
        ('2', 'Экипаж'),
        ('3', 'Авиакомпания'),
        ('4', 'Фрилансер'),
        ('5', 'Пассажир')
    )

    category = models.CharField('Категория',max_length=120, null=True, blank=True, default='0',choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES)
    translations = TranslatedFields(interview = models.TextField('Опрос', null=True, blank=True),)
    nofify = models.BooleanField('Оповестить пользователей о новом вопросе', default=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' qq '

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Опрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Опрос'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None and self.nofify == True:
            send((self.category,))

        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

По логике при cоздании модели должно приходить оповещение всем пользователям в бот, но этого не происходит D:

при запуске `celery -A freenfobot worker -l info`

```
-------------- celery@milkiweedgtlt v3.1.25 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-116-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         freenfobot:0x7fee49616518
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . bot.models.send

[2018-03-16 01:29:12,548: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2018-03-16 01:29:12,560: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-03-16 01:29:13,570: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-03-16 01:29:13,583: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/freenfobot/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
[2018-03-16 01:29:13,584: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@milkiweedgtlt ready.
```

Никаких ошибок нету, функция просто не хочет выполнятся, подскажите пожалуйста, в способ это решить, или есть какая-нибудь альтернатива?

Comment: Зачем передаете кортеж send((self.category,)) ? Т.е. функция даже не начинает выполняться ? . Вставьте в начало фукции logger.debug("1212312")

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#calling-tasks):

```
send.apply_async((self.category,))
```

Comment: http://dpaste.com/092E284. Не подскажите из-за чего возникает эта ошибка? К слову, чтоб не смущало ничего в логах, я переименовал Question в NewNew

Comment: Celery не может подключиться к брокеру.